# Post by jQuery serialize() / serializearray() excluding textarea

Tags: php, jquery

When posting via jQuery serialize method all array elements are being captured except for the text area. I verify the same result from var_dump and Firebug.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#btnJQ").on("click", function() { //100
    var jqxhr = 'a=crea_inv&' + $('#frmData').find('input[name^="empl"]').serialize();
    console.log(jqxhr)
    $.post('jq.php', {
      'empl': jqxhr
    }, function(response) {
      $(".result").html(response);
    }); //.100
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="frmData" action="" method="post">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>ID</td>
      <td>First Name</td>
      <td>Last Name</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" name="empl[0][id]" value="2135" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="empl[0][first_name]" value="John" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="empl[0][last_name]" value="Doe" /></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <textarea id="lnotes" name="empl[0][lnotes]" rows="4" cols="50">
        At .com you will learn how to make a website. We offer free tutorials in all web development technologies.
        </textarea>
  <br>

  <button id="btnJQ" type="button">JQ</button>

  <input type="submit" name="Submit" />
</form>
```

However using the standard submit, textarea value is showing.

```
<?php
//parse array to readable str
$post_data = $_POST['empl'];
parse_str($_POST['empl'],$new_data);

//Now We have the new array saved in a variable called $new_data
 print_r($new_data);

?>
```

Result by var_dump and firebug.

```
Array
(
    [a] => crea_inv
    [empl] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 2135
                    [first_name] => John
                    [last_name] => Doe
                )

        )

)
```

Result by standard form submit

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 2135 [first_name] => John [last_name] => Doe [lnotes] => At .com you will learn how to make a website. We offer free tutorials in all web development technologies. ) ) At .com you will learn how to make a website. We offer free tutorials in all web development technologies.
```

Answer (score 0):

`textarea` is not `input`

You can use `$(":input[name^=empl]")` or just `$("[name^=empl]")`

```js
$(function() {
  $("#btnJQ").on("click", function() { //100
    $('#frmData').find('[name^="empl"]').each(function() { console.log(this.name)} )
var jqxhr = 'a=crea_inv&' + $('#frmData').find('[name^="empl"]').serialize();

console.log(jqxhr)
    $.post('jq.php', {
      'empl': jqxhr
    }, function(response) {
      $(".result").html(response);
    }); //.100
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="frmData" action="" method="post">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>ID</td>
      <td>First Name</td>
      <td>Last Name</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" name="empl[0][id]" value="2135" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="empl[0][first_name]" value="John" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="empl[0][last_name]" value="Doe" /></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <textarea id="lnotes" name="empl[0][lnotes]" rows="4" cols="50">
        At .com you will learn how to make a website. We offer free tutorials in all web development technologies.
        </textarea>
  <br>

  <button id="btnJQ" type="button">JQ</button>

  <input type="submit" name="Submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: This works perfectly $("[name^=empl]"). Thanks @mplungjan.